# Triangle wave generation without using op amp

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, resistors

Is there any way where i can generate triangle wave without using op amp but by only using  mosfets cap and resistors ?

Comment: Yes. Design a discrete MOSFET based op-amp and then take away parts that you don't need for this single use case.

Comment: Similar how it is done in 555 timer with capacitor charged and discharged by constant current sources, not resistors (see 555 internal in datasheet). All it is just one SR latch and two simple comparators for top and bottom.

Comment: Please explain why you can't use an op-amp.

Comment: Square wave circuit and filter

Answer (score 0):

I probably know what you mean with a triangle wave, and I can't really think of a way of doing one without either digital circuits or opamps.

You can generate triangle looking things by filtering a square wave or with 2 transistor relaxation oscillators.

Depending on how you make them (they are really iffy) Joule thiefs (thieves?) or blocking oscillators can generate triangle looking waves.

Some times a smoothed exponential is good enough.

Try looking at the Circuits -> Transistor -> multivibrator -> astable multivibrator tab in here:
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html